# Issues to install Perl Modules on CentOS 7

Tags: perl

I’ve been trying to install some Perl modules on CentOS 7 and facing issues with a bunch of them. I tried with yum, cpan and cpanm (from scratch whenever I tried a different method), and they seem to be built correctly as per installation logs, but when I run my script with “use Module_Name;” it returns issues with dependencies having outdated versions. One of the modules is Date::Locale. Another one is URI::Encode. Is there a correct way to install Perl modules on CentOS 7, without tweaks or manual intervention?

Output requested by ikegami on comments below:

```
/usr/bin/perl
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/root/perl5/lib/perl5
/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5

PERL5LIB: /root/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT: /root/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT: --install_base "/root/perl5"
PERL_MM_OPT: INSTALL_BASE=/root/perl5
cpan is /root/perl5/bin/cpan
#!/usr/bin/perl
    make               [/usr/bin/make]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make]
    makepl_arg         []
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       []
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 12 Apr 2019 17:29:03 GMT
Fetching with LWP:
http://CPAN.mirror.rafal.ca/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://CPAN.mirror.rafal.ca/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Tue, 16 Apr 2019 03:17:02 GMT
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://CPAN.mirror.rafal.ca/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
DONE
Writing /root/.cpan/Metadata
URI::Encode is up to date (1.1.1).
```

Comment: Are the modules installed into the path mentioned in @INC?

Comment: Like this Date::Locale is in the paths of @INC, but I receive messages that the dependencies are not.

Comment: Please provide the output of the `perl -le'print $^X; print for @INC; print "$_: $ENV{$_}" for sort grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV;'; type cpan; head -n 1 "$( which cpan )"; echo 'o conf' | cpan 2>&1 | perl -ne'print if /^\s*(make|mbuild)/'; perl -MURI::Encode -e1; cpan URI::Encode; perl -MURI::Encode -e1`

Comment: Use `@ikegami` in a comment when you do. (If you replace any words in the output for privacy, make sure each word you replace is replaced with a different word, and make sure that each word you replace is always replaced with the same word e.g. all aaa => xxx, all bbb => yyy, etc)

Comment: @ikegami, I'm editing the main question with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing modules through CPAN on Centos7, the modules' path is usually set to `use lib '/root/perl5/lib/perl5'` by CPAN's autoconfigure.

Look for one of the modules you've installed via CPAN (`find / -name module_name`) and look at its path. If it's outside of the default dir, you can add this path in your script.

Comment: I'd also add that using a local::lib in root's homedir is not normal, and you can resolve this by either not using `sudo cpan` (and thus using a local::lib in your user's homedir), or by removing the `perl-homedir` yum package.

Comment: Thanks, @Reinaldo Gomes. That was very useful. I'm still running into some issues with the dependencies reporting outdated versions, and whenever I make a correction I found another problem. I was more looking for a definitive method of installing Perl modules on CentOS7 without having to troubleshoot from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @Grinnz . I will try your recommendations and see if I have improvements.

Comment: The "safest" way of installing perl's modules on CentOS is by using YUM. The downside is that you are subject to module's outdated versions. You could check "software collections" repo to try and circumvent that restriction, though.